# Is aria role="alert" announced on page load?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Will content with `role="alert"` be announced by screen readers on page load?

I have seen contradicting advise from MDN on this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Alert_Role states:

> [T]he alert role is that it is for dynamic content ... if a page loads with multiple visible alerts scattered throughout, none would be read because they are not dynamically triggered.

While another [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_alert_role) states it can be used with static content:

> ## Example 1: Adding the role in the HTML code
>
> The snippet below shows how the alert role is added directly into the html source code. The moment the element finishes loading the screen reader should be notified of the alert. If the element was already in the original source code when the page loaded, the screen reader will announce the error immediately after announcing the page title.

Can/should the alert role be used on static content or only for live regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that it isn't reliably read out. Some screenreaders do read out the alert, but others don't. We've partially got round this issue by also moving focus to the element with role="alert" on, as that's also often a trigger for reading an element out. It also makes sense that if a page reloads and a message is read out, the user will expect their focus to be on that message.

This codepen is quite useful in showing the impact of using role=alert in different ways: codepen.io/vloux/full/JOwxmO

There is a [discussion in the aria Github repo](https://github.com/w3c/aria/issues/1360) about adding a new property that reads on page load. Whether or not this is done (there is some disagreement), there is definitely a gap on what the behaviour should be and this needs to be defined.